# Node.js multiple async request with 10 sec delay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, concurrency

So, I am currently bombarding an api with multiple requests with an delay of 10 seconds each between subsequent requests, so here is the approach I am making us of to tackle delay & api calls.

```
  try {
    const url = `***********`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    if (response.data) {
      for (let user of response.data) {
        if (user.activated === 0) {
          notActivatedUsers.push(user);
          await sendConfirmationEmail(user.email);
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
```

Approach works fine as I am `respecting api call limit`.

My question is more about `scalability & performance`, like can I have heard about libraries like `bluebird`, `lodash` providing methods like `throttle` , `debounce` to tackle these kind of problems. So, I am just curious to know other ways to tackle kind of problem, nothing else & I also have intuition that doing api calls in for loop is not a good practise. I hope you understand me now.

I don't know how scalable it is like if I run the loop until 20k will it still work fine?  As I don't have huge dataset to test on.

Comment: What does "make it better" mean in your example?  the only requirement you've given us is that it should issue requests 10 seconds apart and this does that.  What else would make it "better"?  One problem for issuing 20k requests is that you don't show any error handling so if `await sendConfirmationEmail(user.email);` ever rejects, your loop will be aborted.

Comment: @jfriend00 I will take care of handling, but my question is more about scalability & performance, like can I have heard about libraries like bluebird, lodash providing methods like throttle , debounce to tackle these kind of problems so I am just curious to know other ways to tackle kind of problem, nothing else & I also have intuition that doing api calls in for loop is not a good practise. I hope you understand me now.

Comment: API calls using `await` in a loop works just fine (with proper error handling).  There are probably more effective ways to get 20k API calls made than pausing a somewhat arbitrary 10 seconds between each, but that depends entirely upon exactly what rate limiting algorithm the target server is using and we have no idea what that is.  And, if you knew more about what the rate limit actually was and how it works, there are likely modules out there that would help you implement to that more effectively than just a pause for 10 seconds.  Other than that, you're fine.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks sounds good to me :)